# Error while adding event listners to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning canvas and HTML5

I wanted to run a function when canvas is clicked but my code is not working please help.
My code is as follows

```
 <center><canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas></center>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    Canvas = function(canvasel,width,height)
              {
                   this.el = canvasel;
                    this.el.width = width;
                    this.el.height = height;
                    this.ctx = canvasel.getContext("2d");

              }    


  var canvas = new Canvas(document.querySelector("#mycanvas"),300,300);      


     canvas.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('gg') }, false);
     canvas.ctx.moveTo(50,50);
     canvas.ctx.lineTo(250,250);            
     canvas.ctx.stroke();
     canvas.ctx.closePath();
     canvas.ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);


</script>
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: `canvas.el.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('gg') }, false);` ...Add eventlistener on DOM target element..

Comment: that helped me i have one more question now instead of alert i want to connect that to a function that ive added in the script, how should i do that? i tried <br/>canvas.el.addEventListener('click', functionname(), false); <br/>but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the event listener to the DOM Element that you are passing into your Canvas constructor.

So rather than doing:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('gg') }, false);
```

You should do:

```
canvas.el.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('gg') }, false);
```

Comment: that helped me
i have one more question now instead of alert i want to connect that to a function that ive added in the script, how should i do that?
i tried   canvas.el.addEventListener('click', functionname(), false);
but it didnt work

Comment: Just do: canvas.el.addEventListener('click', functionname, false); This means that you will pass a reference to the function. If you add "()" you will just pass the result of the function, which is most likely just void.

Answer (score 0):

first you should have done something like this,

```
canvas.el.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('gg') }, false);
```

Now that you have asked, here is what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/oz94z8jn/

```
function somefunc(){
alert("try me");
}
canvas.el.addEventListener('click', somefunc, false);
```